# How to set Google home device in “listen mode” with node red

Tags: speech-to-text, node-red, google-home, home-assistant

Is there a way to make a node where you can "make" a conversation with google home mini device?
You already can send TTS and it will anounce whatever you type, but is there a way to wait for a response from the end user and receive (his response) STT back into node red?

The end goal is to let Google home mini ask you for input and based on the response you can activate a flow within Node red. But for that you need to activate your speaker into some kind of "listen mode", like you do when saying "hey google"

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you want the flow to do

If it can be triggered by trying to control a "device" e.g. " hey Google, turn on kitchen light" then there are 3 or 4 nodes/services that will do that. e.g. [node-red-contrib-googlehome](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-googlehome) (full disclosure I wrote and run this one)

There are also some nodes to help with none smart home actions e.g. [node-red-contrib-gactions-fulfillment](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-gactions-fulfillment)

But you will have to trigger it, you cannot have the device initiate the interaction iirc

Comment: As an example:

So lets say I want to trigger an action based if somebody comes downstairs. So the trigger is a sensor which detects motion and I want a google device to ask me if I am doing alright.

If my answer is "okay i am fine" I want to receive this response and start flow number 1, but if my response is "i am not feeling okay" I want to start flow number 2.

Can the sensor "activate" my google device to listen...

Comment: That's not possible, you can not trigger an action like that, you have to initiate it via voice (or on a phone it's possible by typing)

Comment: So it's possible by typing? So if my typing command will be "hey google" it will listen after that command? So you can simulate it (by sending the text) as if it would "hear" it in actual words.

Comment: No, at the google assistant prompt on the phone you can drop the "hey google," but you still need to enter the rest of the command that starts the action, and Google will response in text on the phone, it will NOT trigger the devices to listen. As I've said multiple times, what you want is NOT possible.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

When triggered, cast "Are you ok?" and store a flag saying what triggered it and when.

Expect user to say either "OK Google, I'm fine" or "OK Google, I'm not feeling okay"
This triggers actions that look at the flag, and if its not too long ago since it was set, do the appropriate thing.

You could add a timeout to ask again if no reply was given, or to raise an alarm if no response after a number of retries, but that might be prone to false alarms.

This doesn't open google home to listens, it just expect the user to make an ordinary command to google home, that doesn't know that something was casted to it seconds ago.